# P4API.NET equivalence of "p4 files" command to find files in depot

Tags: .net, perforce, p4api.net

I'm using the Perforce .NET APIs P4API.NET library and wonder if there is a "p4 files" command line equivalence that I can call to return a listing of files (such as *.cpp) in my //depot?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that works for me.

```
IList<FileSpec> filesToFind = new List<FileSpec>();
FileSpec fileToFind = new FileSpec(new DepotPath("//depot/....cpp"), null, null, VersionSpec.Head);
filesToFind.Add(fileToFind);
IList<FileSpec> filesFound = pRep.GetDepotFiles(filesToFind, null);
```

Comment: When a depot path has no file, I got an exception from pRep.GetDepotFiles(fileToFind, null) instead of it returning null.  The exception is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick tour around [the docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/Index.html) doesn't immediately reveal anything, but you could always use `P4Command.Run` to run any arbitrary Perforce command, so you could still run `p4 files //depot/...cpp`.

Comment: How do I get the output back from p4Command.Run for the "p4 files ..." command?

Comment: The introduction in the docs I linked to in my answer will give you that answer.

`P4CommandResult results = cmd.Run(opts);`